# Unable to find button with selenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I had a similar issue the other day and I resolved this by using the xpath as the element I was looking for was not in the original URL

I am trying to make a script to unfollow somebody on instagram and I am able to get to their profile page - it is just a matter of locating the button. I have tried using xpath and css selector

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\*\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/")

elem2 = driver.find_element_by_name("username")
elem2.send_keys('*')
elem3 = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
elem3.send_keys('*')
elem3.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
while True:
    try:
        elem4 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".-Cab_, .bIiDR")
        elem4.click()
        break
    except Exception:
        pass


names = ['chucknorris']
for i in names:
    elem5 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/nav/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/input')   
    elem5.send_keys(i)
    time.sleep(1)
    while True:
        try:
            elems = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("yCE8d")
            elems[0].click()
            break
        except Exception:
            pass

##    while True:
##        try:
##            elemL = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/header/section/div[2]/div/span/span[1]')
##        except Exception:
##            pass
#This part was just so I got the error message rather than infinite loop of nothing
    time.sleep(4)
    elemL = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/header/section/div[2]/div/span/span[1]/button')
    elemL.click()
```

'elemL' is the desired button element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original xpath failed for 2 reasons.

1. The element with id "react-root" is a span and not a div. (It worked in your other xpath because you had a *)
2. The child div under the section element is the first div, not the second.

Another option would be to just do this (if you are confident the text of the button won't change too often:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]//main//button[.="Following"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer was to use driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.-fzfL') which was the one which had background color attrib etc (really not sure if that's important)